# Zeros of characters

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory, characters

I was wondering if the following is true:

Let $\chi$ and $\chi'$ be two irreducible characters over $\mathbb{C}$ of a finite group with same degree. 
Suppose that $\chi(g) = 0 \implies \chi'(g) = 0$. 
Is true that $\chi'(g) = 0 \implies \chi(g) = 0$?

In other words, can the zero set of a character be a strict subset of the zero set of another character of the same degree?

Any counter-example or help proving this is appreciated.

Comment: Yes. Both characters are irreducible.

Comment: Is the group finite?

Comment: I was thinking of a finite group, but a counter-example with an infinite group might help.

Comment: If a group $G$ has a dimension $n-1$ irreducible representation such that $\forall g\in G,\chi(g)\ne 0$ then $G\times S_n$ provides a counter-example, as the character  of $S_n$ permuting the coordinates on $\{x\in K^n, \sum_j x_j=0\}$ vanishes at $(1)(23\ldots n)$.
Did you mean irreducible **complex** representation?
If not then $\mu_3\times S_3$ provides a counter-example with $\chi(\zeta_3)=Tr({\scriptstyle\pmatrix{0&-1\\-1&-1}})$ which is irreducible over $K=\Bbb{Q}$.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion. I meant absolutely irreducible.

Comment: If $G$ is allowed to be an infinite group then take it to be the free group generated by 2 elements and use a countability argument to find a dimension 2 irreducible complex representation whose character never vanishes.

Comment: Yes, that is true, but I think the result should still be true for finite groups.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out the [dihedral group $D_{12}$](https://people.maths.bris.ac.uk/%7Ematyd/GroupNames/1/D12.html).